# If $q(x)\le 0$ on an interval $I$, then no non-trivial solution $y''+q(x)y=0$ an have two zeros on $I$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $q(x)\le 0$ on an interval $I$, then no non-trivial solution $y''+q(x)y=0$ an have two zeros on $I$.

here what my problem is when i trying to understanding this problem the author says that

Suppose if possible, that a non-trivial solution $y$ has at least two zeroes on $I$.
WLOG let $x_1 < x_2$ be two consecutive zeroes of $y,$ and that $y > 0 $ on $(x_1, x_2)$

This implies that
    $$ y'(x_1)>0$$ and $$y'(x_2)<0$$

how we conclude that the last statement can some one tell me please

Comment: Are you sure about the assumptions? Set $q(x)=1$, then the solution $y=\cos(x)$ has two solutions on the interval $[0,2\pi]$. The claim is true for $q(x)<0$.

Comment: @LutzL.....sorry sir typo mistake ue correct

Comment: So if you have a maximum (or minimum) at $x_1<x^*<x_2$. Then $y(x^*)$ must be positive, but $y''(x^*)\le 0$. Now look how that fits together with the ODE...

Comment: Is there any assumption on $q$ apart from it being non-positive?  Is it at least continuous?

Comment: @Zvi....q is continuous sir

Comment: You still didn't fix the typo in the title though.  It still says $q(x)\geq 0$ there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $q$ is strictly negative, this problem is relatively easy.  But the trouble comes when $q$ can be zero.  I don't think my solution is optimal, but well, it solves the problem.

---

First, we claim that, if there exists $a\in I$ such that $y(a)=0$ and $y'(a)=0$, then $y$ is the trivial solution.  To prove this, note that $y$ is continuous.  Without loss of generality, we assume that there exists $b\in I$ such that $b>a$.  (Otherwise replace $y:I\to\Bbb R$ by $\tilde{y}:(-I)\to\Bbb R$, where $\tilde{y}(x)=y(-x)$ for all $x\in I$.)

Fix $\epsilon>0$ such that $[a,a+\epsilon]\subset I$.  Then, there exists $L_\epsilon>0$ such that $\big|y(x)\big|\leq L_\epsilon$ for all $x\in [a,a+\epsilon]$.  Since $q$ is continuous, there exists $M_\epsilon$ such that $\big|q(x)\big|\leq M_\epsilon$ for all $x\in[a,a+\epsilon]$.  By the differential equation $y''+qy=0$, we have
$$\big|y'(a+s)\big|=\left|\int_a^{a+s} y''(t)\ dt\right|\leq \int_a^{a+s}\big|q(t)\big|\big|y(t)\big|\ dt\leq L_\epsilon M_\epsilon  s.\tag{1}$$
Thus,
$$\big|y(a+s)\big|=\left|\int_a^{a+s}y'(t)\ dt\right|\leq \int_a^{a+s}\big|y'(t)\big|\ dt\leq \int_0^{s} L_\epsilon M_\epsilon  t\ dt=\frac{L_\epsilon  M_\epsilon s^2}{2}.\tag{2}$$

We can plug in (2) into (1), and then improve the bound of (1), which then leads to an improved bound for (2).  By doing this many times over, we get
$$\big|y'(a+s)\big|\leq \frac{L_\epsilon M_\epsilon^n s^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}$$
and
$$\big|y(a+s)\big|\leq \frac{L_\epsilon M_\epsilon^n s^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ for every natural number $n$.  Letting $n\to\infty$, we get $y'(a+s)=y(a+s)=0$ for all $s$ with $0\leq s\leq \epsilon$.

We can repeat the process until we show that $y(x)=0$ for all $x\in I$ with $x\geq a$.  If $\inf I\neq a$, we can reverse the direction and prove in the same manner that $y(x)=0$ for all $x\in I$ with $x\leq a$.  Hence, $y$ is trivial on the whole $I$.

---

If $y(x_1)=0$ and $y(x_2)=0$ for some $x_1,x_2\in I$ with $x_1<x_2$, and $y$ is non-trivial, then by the result above, $y$ is not identically zero on $[x_1,x_2]$.  Following LutzL's hint, the continuous function $y$ is both maximized and minimized in the compact interval $[x_1,x_2]$.  Either the maximum value or the minimum value of $y$ in $[x_1,x_2]$ is nonzero.  WLOG, the maximum value is nonzero, and achieved when $x=c$.

That is, $y''(c)\leq 0$.    As $y''(c)=\big(-q(c)\big)y(c)\geq 0$ because $q\leq 0$ on $I$, we must have $q(c)=0$.  Let $u$ denote the infimum of $t\in[x_1,c]$ such that $q$ vanishes on $[t,c]$, and $v$ the supremum of $t\in[c,x_2]$ such that $q$ vanishes on $[c,t]$.  Either $u>x_1$ or $v<x_2$ must hold, otherwise, $q=0$ on $[x_1,x_2]$, and $y$ is linear there.  If $y$ is non-trivial and linear on $[x_1,x_2]$, it cannot have two zeros on $[x_1,x_2]$.

We will only deal with the case $u>x_1$ here, but the case $v<x_2$ can be proven similarly.  First, if $u=c$, we see that, for a sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, we have $c-s>x_1$, $y(c-s)>0$, and $q(c-s)<0$ if $0<s<\epsilon$.  We get that $$y''(c-s)=-q(c-s)y(c-s)>0.$$  Consequently, $$y'(u-s)=-\int_{u-s}^uy''(t)\ dt<0.$$
That is, $y$ is decreasing in $[u-\epsilon,u]$, so $y(u-\epsilon)>y(u)=y(c)$, contradicting the assumption that $x=c$ maximizes $y$ on $[x_1,x_2]$.

If $u<c$, then it is easy to prove that either $y'=0$ on $[u,v]$ with $v>c$, or $y'\geq 0$ on $[u,v]$ with $v=c$.  In the case $y'=0$ on $[u,v]$, $y$ is a positive constant on $[u,v]$.  For a sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, we have $u-s>x_1$, $y(u-s)>0$, and $q(u-s)<0$ if $0<s<\epsilon$.  We get that $$y''(u-s)=-q(u-s)y(u-s)>0.$$  Consequently, $$y'(c-s)=-\int_{c-s}^cy''(t)\ dt<0.$$
That is, $y$ is decreasing in $[c-\epsilon,c]$, so $y(c-\epsilon)>y(c)$, contradicting the assumption that $x=c$ maximizes $y$ on $[x_1,x_2]$.

Hence, for $u<c$, we are left with the case $y'\geq 0$ and $v=c$.  Therefore, for a small $\epsilon>0$, we have $c+s<x_2$, $y(c+s)>0$, and $q(c+s)<0$ if $0<s<\epsilon$.  That is, $y''(c+s)=-q(c+s)y(c+s)>0$ and
$$y'(c+s)=\int_c^{c+s}y''(t)\ dt>0.$$
That is, $y$ is increasing on $[c,c+\epsilon]$, so $y(c+\epsilon)>y(c)$, contradicting the assumption that $x=c$ maximizes $y$ on $[x_1,x_2]$.

Comment: You seem to assume in the bound for $y'(a+s)$ that $y'(a)=0$ after having discussed and excluded that case previously

Comment: @LutzL I was trying to prove that there is no nontrivial solution with $y(a)=y'(a)=0$ at some point $a\in I$.  So, yes, I assumed $y'(a)=0$.  I don't see that this (seemingly trivial) result has been discussed and excluded, except in my answer.  But then, in a differential equation like this, knowing $y(a)$ and $y'(a)$ determines $y$ completely, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: The equation is linear with continuous coefficients, so existence and uniqueness is guaranteed by Picard-Lindelöf. $y=0$ is a solution with $y(a)=0=y'(a)$ and thus it is the only solution. There are no non-trivial alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y$ be a solution with at least one root. Let that root w.l.o.g. be at $x=0$ and also $y'(0)=1$ after rescaling. Now fix some $x>0$ and consider
$$
g_x(t)=y(t)+(x-t)y'(t)~~\implies g_x(0)=x,~~ g_x(x)=y(x)
$$
so that 
$$
g_x'(t)=y'(t)-y'(t)+(x-t)y''(t)=-(x-t)q(t)y(t)
$$
As long as $y(t)>0$ for $t\in(0,x)$ we get $g'(t)\ge 0$ on the same interval. Thus
$$
y(x)-x=g_x(x)-g_t(0)=\int_0^x g_x'(s)\,ds\ge 0
$$ 
Which means $y(x)\ge x$ so that there can be no second root $x>0$. By symmetry the same applies for $x<0$.

---

The above was obtained by comparing the solutions for the given $q$ to the ones for $q=0$, $y''=0$ with $y(x)=0$, $y'(x)=1$ with solutions $u(t;x)=(t-x)$ and then considering the Wronski-like determinant $$\det\pmatrix{y(t)&u(t;x)\\y'(t)&\partial_tu(t;x)}.$$ One could as well start in this case with the linear Taylor polynomial with integral remainder term,
$$
y(x)=y(0)+y'(0)x+\int_0^x(x-t)y''(t)\,dt
$$
leading to the same argument.